# Steps to extend Drive C by using 200 GB of Drive D

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

Provided the configuration that I have in the following picture, please let me know the steps of extending my Drive C from Disk0 by using 200 GB of Drive D from Disk1.
Kindly note that Disk0 is Dynamic and Disk1 is Basic.
I'm running Computer Management as Administrator on Windows 10.
I have added pictures to show right click options available for my case.

[image: Current Configuration]
[image: Right Click Options]
[image: Right Click Options]
[image: Right Click Options]

Comment: @SamForbis: "Dynamic Disks" allows it (this is kind of the whole point; it's like LVM for Windows), but I'm already surprised that it doesn't interfere with EFI boot in OP's current system...

Comment: @user1686 Thanks for correcting me, learned something new today. I'll delete my original comment.

Comment: The EASY way?  Use NTFS junctions!  You can move a huge amount to the second drive and junction it back to the same folder name.  Apps that use it won't know the difference.  Also.. if this is for a fresh empty folder.. just make a junction from drive 2 to drive 1.

Comment: You can't extend a system volume or the boot volume. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc737048(v=ws.10) Dynamic disks are deprecated in Windows 10 https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/planning/windows-10-deprecated-features

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to span a partition across multiple disks, you need to convert all disks to Dynamic disks first. Your first disk is a dynamic disk already, but your second disk is still a basic disk.

Right-click it, choose: convert to dynamic disk.

Once done, you can create a partition that spans both dynamic disks.

That said, you may need to remove the partitions and create new spanned or striped partitions, which means that you cannot perform this operation because C is your windows drive. In this instance, you need to do this from outside of windows, for example, boot windows setup, hit alt-f10 to access command prompt, and use DiskPart to do the actions. Make sure you make backups first. I suggest to create and move all data of the C partition to the D disk, so you can remove the C partition without affecting windows, but you may be required to reinstall windows. Keep in mind that if you convert both disks to dynamic disks, you should be able to create the spanned drive from the windows setup itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot @LPChip, that was insightful answer. Can I just extend the C Drive with the whole D Drive in the same way rather than cutting a space from D?

Comment: No, but only because you cannot extend. You have to remove the partitions first, then in the blank space, you can make new spanned or striped volume across multiple drives. That drive can use the entire 2nd disk and part or all of the 1st disk if you want.